# How can I share a post on my wall using the Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

On my PC, I can repost (share) a post from a friend on my own wall.

How can I do that in the official Android Facebook app?

Answer (score 3):

You can re-share your friend's post using [FriendCaster for Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.blueNotifyFree) app. Simply install it and use it as your primary fb app. Its better than official fb app in many aspects..

**Update (November 2012):**
In recent version of official Facebook app, this feature has been added. Happy Re-Sharing!